# Dynamics 365: different behavior for programatically enabled readonly lookups

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

If a form lookup attribute is customized as readonly and activated programatically using the setDisabled javascript method, its behavior is different to lookups which are not customized as readonly:

a single click in the blank spot of the lookup (not on the text) triggers the redirection to the lookup's entity (if not not empty) instead of selecting the lookup and enabling text input.

Is there a way to enable the same behavior without changing the readonly property in the form customizing?

Version is 8.2.0.749.

Comment: That sounds strange. Which version are you running? I cannot reproduce on 8.2.0.795: [Enabling disabled lookup](https://giphy.com/gifs/3og0IPC7aXsYnNIWWY)

Comment: I don't have a 365 environment to validate, but clicking on the value inside a lookup always takes you to the record in the lookup.  If you click in a blank spot of the lookup (next to the name but still within the lookup), the lookup becomes selected and you can press backspace/delete to remove the value and then start typing.  Is this not the behavior you are seeing?

Answer (score 3):

So I found that for some reason there are [two click handlers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2soD5.png) registered on the "readonly" lookup dom element. This is not the case, if the lookup is not set to readonly in form customizing. A hacky unsupported workaround would be the following javascript:

```
var domElement = document.getElementById("transactioncurrencyid");
if (domElement && domElement.children && domElement.children[0]) {
    var div = domElement.children[0];
    if (div && div._events && div._events.click && div._events.click.length === 2) {                        
        div.removeEventListener('click', div._events.click[0].browserHandler, false);
        div.removeEventListener('click', div._events.click[1].browserHandler, false);                        
    }
}
```